# How to inject EntityManagerInterface in any class (specifically a command helper)

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to figure out how to inject EntityManagerInterface in any class which is not a controller or some Symfony specific classes.
For example I have a custom console Helper:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Helper;

class EntityManagerHelper extends Helper
{

/**
* Doctrine ORM EntityManagerInterface.
*
* @var EntityManagerInterface
*/
protected $_em;

/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
 */
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->_em = $em;
}
....
```

Which has in the constructor EntityManagerInterface.
I initialize this class in the Command class this way

```
$this->getHelperSet()->set(new EntityManagerHelper(), 'em');
```

But it complaints

```
Too few arguments to function App\Command\Helper\EntityManagerHelper::__construct(), 0 passed
```

What I'm missing ?

Comment: Container features don't work when using `new`. Just autowire the classes directly.

Comment: Hadn't realized you were instantiating the class directly. That's not autowiring. Just inject your `EntityManagerHelper` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First solution : Make your EntityManagerHelper as autowired service

```php
class EntityManagerHelper extends Helper 
{
    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->_em = $em;
    } 
}
```

Your class can be autowired because it is in a folder not excluded for this.

And you call it in your class like this :

```php
class YourClass
{
    public function  __construct(EntityManagerHelper $helper)
    {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    public function tada()
    {
        $this->getHelperSet()->set($this->helper, 'em');
    }
}
```

Second solution : Inject directly EntityManagerInterface in your class

```php
class YourClass
{
    public function  __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function tada()
    {
        $this->getHelperSet()->set(new EntityManagerHelper($this->em), 'em');
    }
}
```